# C++ sqrt returns -1.#IND000000000000

Tags: c++, sqrt

In specific:

Im doing some math operations, and the application keeps crashing because a double that is widely used happens to get the value: -1.#IND000000000000 when "some" numbers are sqrt'ed...
What is this? Indefinite? Infinite? Too big to fit? Not a perfect Square Root? Is there any way to solve this?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: How can i check if a double has this value ? I tried:  if (x == 0x-1.#IND000000000000) and other variations but did not work. Is it possible to check to see if a variable has this value ?

Comment: are `some numbers` less than 0 perhaps? Tell me sir, what is the sqrt of -1

Comment: Clearly EnabrenTane meant, "What is the IEEE 754 sqrt of -1.0?"

Comment: @Noah Roberts: i is hard to represent as a floating point number. Maybe it could return a char :-)

Comment: I'm willing to bet the cause isn't `sqrt(-1)` but `sqrt(-1E-20)` or so. This happens when two approxiamtely equal terms almost cancel, e.g. `sqrt(100.0/3.0 - (50.0/3.0 + 50.0/3.0))`. Due to limited FP precision, this argument isn't exactly `0.0` and may be rounded to a negative number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the string `-1.#IND000000000000` is not a value, returned by a function, but it is one of a common representations of a `QNaN`, `Quiet Not-a-Number`, the special IEEE-754 value representing the invalid number, that won't cause the exception (there are also `SNaN`, `Signalling NaN`, which would cause the floating point exception, if enabled). The common cause of this is calling a function with argument out of it's domain.

Comment: Yes, many certain bit layout's represent the same "value of NaN".

Answer (score 5):

NaNs (such as the "indeterminate" you have and "infinity") can be detected by checking `x == x` (it's false for NaN and true for any finite number).

Answer (score 2):

The value `#IND000000000000` represents an invalid numeric value. This is often called a QNaN (Quiet Not-A-Number) value because it represents an indeterminate type but does not cause calculations to fail.

Chances are, the elusive numbers whose square root you're attempting to determine are *negative* numbers, for which that value is not defined. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_negative_and_complex_numbers) for more information.

Solving it will first require you to determine *where* the problem is occurring. That means you either need to step through yourself it with a debugger and watch the values of the variables, or post your code so that we can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the argument is negative, a domain error occurs, setting the global variable errno to the value EDOM.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a complex type, sqrt of any value below 0 is meant to cause an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's a NaN (Not A Number). It means you've called sqrt with a negative argument.

Cheers & hth.,